# EPPlus multiple tabs c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to export an excel. I have done some functions to get a "ExcelWorksheet". I would like join all of them in one excel(one per tab) using it but I don't know how can I do it.

here is the main function:

```
public ActionResult ExportReports(string sheetName)
{
    try
    {
        var req = GetRequest();
        var fileDownloadName = "OnlineReport.xlsx";
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        var package = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws1 = AnalysisByAirCarrier(package, req);
        var ws2 = Summary(package, req);

        var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(fileStream);
        fileStream.Position = 0;
        var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
        fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

        return fsr;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Error ExportReports", ex);
    }
}
```

I would like join ws1 and ws2 in the same file in different tabs.

note: ws1 and ws2 are ExcelWorksheet objects

any idea??

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *should* be able to add a copy of a worksheet to a workbook as a tab:

```
using(var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("First worksheet 1", ws1);
    package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("First worksheet 2", ws2);
    // Do something with the package
}
```

I'm not sure what you're doing in `AnalysisByAirCarrier` and `Summary` though.

I haven't tested it, but adding blank worksheets and operating on them works just as expected for me (it creates multiple tabs which I can fill with content)

[edit]: Updating "First worksheet" comment

Comment: Thanks, it's workig. I got an error but was because A worksheet with this name already exists in the workbook. I have updated it and it's working ok.

Comment: @gon250 Oh, right, sorry. I thought I changed the worksheet names. I'm glad it works though!

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedSheetList = UserData.GroupBy(u => u.date).Select(grp => grp.ToList 
()).ToList();
using (var package = new ExcelPackage ()) {
foreach (var item in groupedSheetList){
var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add (item[0].date);}}
```